# Can one use Apollo Server caching when one is schema-stitching with 'graphql-tools'?

Tags: caching, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have an Apollo Server that uses `graphql-tools-fork` to do schema-stitching (this Apollo Server acts as an interface between an Apollo Client frontend and several backends, some of which are REST, some of which are GraphQL: the interface combines all of the backends into one GraphQL API for the front).

We want to do caching of API calls from this server to the remote APIs and [Apollo Server caching](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/performance/caching/) was recommended to us as one way to do this. However, near the top of that page it says

> Important note on compatibility: Setting cache hints is currently
>   incompatible with the graphql-tools implementation of schema
>   stitching, because cache hints are not appropriately communicated from
>   one service to the other.

It's unclear to me whether this means that all Apollo Server caching won't work, or whether only the hinting.  That is, whether the entire documentation page above is moot if you're using schema-stitching, or whether part of it -- for instance [Serving HTTP cache headers](http://Serving%20HTTP%20cache%20headers) -- is still valid.  I suspect that one can't use caching at all, since `Serving HTTP cache headers` seems to depend on `maxAge`,  which seems to depend on the cache hints.

Any clues much appreciated!